# Selecting the degree of spline function based on a set R^2 threshold value

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly

I am developing a shiny app in which I am plotting scatterplot and a spline fit function on it, the degree of spline function can be changed by a slider whose values varies from 2-12, shown below:

```
ui <- tabPanel(sidebarLayout(
                           sidebarPanel(sliderInput('degree', 'Degree of the Polynomial:', min = 2, max = 12, value = 3, step = 1)),
                           mainPanel(plotlyOutput("plot"))))
```

Below is the server side code:

```
server <- function(input, output, session){
          observeEvent(input$degree, {
          output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    
           m <- lm(formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, df = input$degree), df4)
            #plot
            g <- ggplot(data =  df4, aes_string(x = df4$x, y = df4$y)) + theme_bw() +
              geom_point(colour = "blue", size = 0.1)+
              geom_smooth(formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, df = input$degree), method = "lm", color = "green3", level = 1, size = 1)
            h <- g + xlab("X (mm)") + ylab("Z (um)")
            
            ggplotly(h) %>% add_annotations(text= sprintf("R^2: %f", summary(m)[8]), xref="paper", yref="paper", x=0.05,y=0.9)
    })
    })
}
```

`df4` is the dataset that has been used to plot the scatterplot, which looks like this:
[image]

Now I want the value of the degree of spline fit to get selected automatically based on the R^2 value.

For example, if 0.8 is the set threshold for the `R^2` value, then that degree of spline function should get automatically selected as the default value of the slider, where the value of `R^2` crosses the threshold of 0.8 for the first time.

All in all, I want the default set value of the slider (which is set to 3 here) to be dynamic based on the set threshold value of `R^2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.  You need to estimate the model outside of the rendered output so you can identify the correct degree.  Then, you need to use `renderUI()` to build the slider so you can pass the identified value of degree to the `value` argument.  Then, you can make the plot without being inside the event observer because it's already a reactive function and observing the degree input slider.

```
ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(uiOutput("slider")), 
  mainPanel(plotlyOutput("plot"))))

server <- function(input, output, session){
  library(ggplot2)
  library(plotly)
  library(splines)
  set.seed(1)
  ## set number of observations
  n <- 400
  ## generate x in [0,1]
  x <- 0:(n-1)/(n-1)
  ## create compled function of x
  f <- 0.2*x^11*(10*(1-x))^6+10*(10*x)^3*(1-x)^10
  ## create y = f(x) + random noise
  y <- f + rnorm(n, 0, sd = 2)
  df4 <- data.frame(x=x, y=y)  
  deg <- 2
  r2 <- 0
  while(r2 < .8){
    deg <- deg + 1
    m <- lm(formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, df = deg), df4)  
    r2 <- summary(m)$r.squared
  }
  output$slider <- renderUI(sliderInput('degree', 
                                        'Degree of the Polynomial:', 
                                        min = 2, 
                                        max = 300, 
                                        value = deg, 
                                        step = 1) )  
    output$plot <- renderPlotly({
      #plot
      m <- lm(formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, df = input$degree), df4)  
      g <- ggplot(data =  df4, aes(x = x, y = y)) + theme_bw() +
        geom_point(colour = "blue", size = 0.1)+
        geom_smooth(formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, df = input$degree), method = "lm", color = "green3", level = 1, size = 1)
      h <- g + xlab("X (mm)") + ylab("Z (um)")
      ggplotly(h) %>% add_annotations(text= sprintf("R^2: %f", summary(m)[8]), xref="paper", yref="paper", x=0.05,y=0.9)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

### EDIT add file upload

I added a file upload button and text box along with variable choosers for the x- and y- variables from the names in the uploaded dataset.

```
ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput('file1', 'Choose file to upload',
                             accept = c(
                               'text/csv',
                               'text/comma-separated-values',
                               'text/tab-separated-values',
                               'text/plain',
                               '.csv',
                               '.tsv'
                             )
  ),
  uiOutput("xvar"), 
  uiOutput("yvar"), 
  uiOutput("slider")), 
  mainPanel(plotlyOutput("plot"))))

server <- function(input, output, session){
  library(ggplot2)
  library(plotly)
  library(splines)
  df4 <- reactive({
    req(input$file1)
    inFile <- input$file1
    read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE)
  })
  output$xvar <- renderUI({
    req(df4())
    selectInput("xvar", "X-variable", choices=names(df4()), selected = NULL)
  })
  output$yvar <- renderUI({
    req(df4())
    selectInput("yvar", "Y-variable", choices=names(df4()), selected = NULL)
  })
  deg <- reactive({
    req(input$yvar)
    degr <- 2
    r2 <- 0
    while(r2 < .8){
      degr <- degr + 1
      form <- paste(input$yvar, "~ splines::bs(", input$xvar, ", df = ", degr, ")")
      m <- lm(formula = form, df4())  
      r2 <- summary(m)$r.squared
    }
    degr
  })
  
  output$slider <- renderUI({
    req(deg())
    sliderInput('degree', 
                                        'Degree of the Polynomial:', 
                                        min = 2, 
                                        max = 300, 
                                        value = deg(), 
                                        step = 1) })  
    output$plot <- renderPlotly({
      req(deg())
      #plot
      form <- paste(input$yvar, "~ splines::bs(", input$xvar, ", df = ", input$degree, ")")
      m <- lm(formula = form, df4())  
      g <- ggplot(data =  df4(), aes_string(x = input$xvar, y = input$yvar)) + theme_bw() +
        geom_point(colour = "blue", size = 0.1)+
        geom_smooth(formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, df = input$degree), method = "lm", color = "green3", level = 1, size = 1)
      h <- g + xlab("X (mm)") + ylab("Z (um)")
      ggplotly(h) %>% add_annotations(text= sprintf("R^2: %f", summary(m)[8]), xref="paper", yref="paper", x=0.05,y=0.9)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I am getting the df4 data by uploading some data files in the shiny app. And when I tried to do it your way it is showing this error: 'Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)'        So, should I include the code in a reactive function?

Comment: @kolas0202 I edited the answer to include a file upload button and choosers for the x- and y-variables from the names of the data set.  As all of these different specifications may change the nature of the answer (as it did here), it would be useful to know from the beginning what the requirements are for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky without some sample data, but suppose we had the following data set:

```r
set.seed(1)

df4 <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = rnorm(10, (1:10)/10))

df4
#>     x          y
#> 1   1 -0.5264538
#> 2   2  0.3836433
#> 3   3 -0.5356286
#> 4   4  1.9952808
#> 5   5  0.8295078
#> 6   6 -0.2204684
#> 7   7  1.1874291
#> 8   8  1.5383247
#> 9   9  1.4757814
#> 10 10  0.6946116
```

When plotted, it looks like this:

```
plot(df)
```

[image]

so it has a slight upwards trend.

If we want to find the number of splines that gives a fit with r squared > 0.8 we can do:

```r
library(splines)

i <- 3

while(summary(lm(formula = y ~ bs(x, df = i), df4))$r.squared < 0.8) i <- i + 1
```

So now i is the lowest number of splines that gives an r squared of 0.8 or more:

```r
i
#> [1] 8
```

And we can fit `i` into our fixed model:

```r
fit <- lm(formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, df = i), df4)
summary(fit)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, df = i), data = df4)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>        1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8 
#>  0.00008 -0.00216  0.01512 -0.04776  0.08208 -0.08208  0.04776 -0.01512 
#>        9       10 
#>  0.00216 -0.00008 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>                         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
#> (Intercept)              -0.5265     0.1360  -3.871   0.1609  
#> splines::bs(x, df = i)1   4.4178     0.4344  10.170   0.0624 .
#> splines::bs(x, df = i)2  -4.1409     0.4194  -9.874   0.0643 .
#> splines::bs(x, df = i)3   5.2151     0.3247  16.064   0.0396 *
#> splines::bs(x, df = i)4  -1.3020     0.3068  -4.244   0.1473  
#> splines::bs(x, df = i)5   2.3384     0.3245   7.206   0.0878 .
#> splines::bs(x, df = i)6   1.9458     0.4199   4.634   0.1353  
#> splines::bs(x, df = i)7   2.0650     0.4309   4.792   0.1310  
#> splines::bs(x, df = i)8   1.2212     0.1924   6.349   0.0995 .
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.136 on 1 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.9974, Adjusted R-squared:  0.9769 
#> F-statistic:  48.6 on 8 and 1 DF,  p-value: 0.1105
```

and

```
lines(10:100/10, predict(fit, newdata = list(x = 10:100/10)), col = "red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-11-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>